# DownloadStringAsync to get a text string?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1, downloadstring

I am trying to create a Windows Phone 7.1 application, basically a currency converter. I am using `DownloadStringAsync` method to get a short string containing the exchange rate from a specific website. I tested in Visual Studio 2010, `DownloadString` worked just fine. But not for the phone application. What do I need to do here? I can't really make much sense of it.

```
Partial Public Class MainPage
Inherits PhoneApplicationPage
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim result As String = Nothing
' Constructor
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    a = "USD"
    b = "GBP"
    webClient = New WebClient
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" + a + "&to=" + b) as String)
    TextBox1.Text = result
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 3):

A few things wrong here:

1. `DownloadStringAsync` does not return a value (`void` method in C# terms)
2. You need to handle the `DownloadStringCompleted` event for `WebClient` variable. You can get the result in the event handler.

You can change your code to something like this to get the above to work:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    a = "USD"
    b = "GBP"
    webClient = New WebClient
    'Add the event handler here
    AddHandler webClient.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf webClient_DownloadStringCompleted            
    Dim url As String = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" & a & "&to=" & b            
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri(url))
End Sub

Private Sub webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(ByVal sender as Object,ByVal e as DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    TextBox1.Text = e.result
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `DownloadStringTaskAsync`:

```
Using WebClient As WebClient = New WebClient
    Return Await WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(New Uri(myurl))
End Using
```